# VB.NET 2010 - Extracting an application resource to the Desktop

Tags: vb.net, io, resources, filestream, my.resources

I am trying to extract an application resource from `My.Resources.FILE`

I have discovered how to do this with DLL & EXE files, but I still need help with the code for extracting PNG & ICO files.

Other file types also. (If possible)

Here is my current code that works with DLL & EXE files.

```
Dim File01 As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\" + "SAMPLE.EXE", IO.FileMode.Create)
            File01.Write(My.Resources.SAMPLE, 0, My.Resources.SAMPLE.Length)
            File01.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the code you have is bad. When using `My.Resources`, every time you use a property, you extract a new copy of the data. That means that your second line is getting the data to write twice, with the second time being only to get its length. At the very least, you should be getting the data only once and assigning it to a variable, then using that variable twice. You should also be using a `Using` statement to create and destroy the `FileStream`. Even better though, just call `File.WriteAllBytes`, which means that you don't have to create your own `FileStream` or know the length of the data to write. You should also not be constructing the file path that way.

```vb
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "SAMPLE.EXE")

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, My.Resources.SAMPLE)
```

As for your question, the important thing to understand here is that it really has nothing to do with resources. The question is really how to save data of any particular type and that is something that you can look up for yourself. When you get the value of a property from `My.Resources`, the type of the data you get will depend on the type of the file you embedded in first place. In the case of a binary file, e.g. DLL or EXE, you will get back a `Byte` array and so you save that data to a file in the same way as you would any other `Byte` array. In the case of an image file, e.g. PNG, you will get back an `Image` object, so you save that like you would any other `Image` object, e.g.

```vb
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "PICTURE.PNG")

Using picture = My.Resources.PICTURE
    picture.Save(filePath, picture.RawFormat)
End Using
```

For an ICO file you will get back an `Icon` object. I'll leave it to you to research how to save an `Icon` object to a file.

EDIT:

It's important to identify what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve. You can obviously get an object from `My.Resources` so that is not the problem. You need to determine what type that object is and determine how to save an object of that type. How to do that will be the same no matter where that object comes from, so the resources part is irrelevant. Think about what it is that you have to do and write a method to do it, then call that method.

In your original case, you could start like this:

```vb
Dim data = My.Resources.SAMPLE
```

Once you have written that - even as you write it - Intellisense will tell you that the data is a `Byte` array. Your actual problem is now how to save a `Byte` array to a file, so write a method that does that:

```vb
Private Sub SaveToFile(data As Byte(), filePath As String)
    '...
End Sub
```

You can now which you want to do first: write code to call that method as appropriate for your current scenario or write the implementation of the method. There are various specific ways to save binary data, i.e. a `Byte` array, to a file but, as I said, the simplest is `File.WriteAllBytes`:

```vb
Private Sub SaveToFile(data As Byte(), filePath As String)
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data)
End Sub
```

As for calling the method, you need to data, which you already have, and the file path:

```vb
Dim data = My.Resources.SAMPLE
Dim folderPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
Dim fileName = "SAMPLE.EXE"
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)

SaveToFile(data, filePath)
```

Simple enough. You need to follow the same steps for any other resource. If you embedded a PNG file then you would find that the data is an `Image` object or, more specifically, a `Bitmap`. Your task is then to learn how to save such an object to a file. It shouldn't take you long to find out that the `Image` class has its own `Save` method, so you would use that in your method:

```vb
Private Sub SaveToFile(data As Image, filePath As String)
    data.Save(filePath, data.RawFormat)
End Sub
```

The code to call the method is basically as before, with the exception that an `image` object needs to be disposed when you're done with it:

```vb
Dim data = My.Resources.PICTURE
Dim folderPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
Dim fileName = "SAMPLE.EXE"
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)

SaveToFile(data, filePath)
data.Dispose()
```

The proper way to create and dispose an object in a narrow scope like this is with a `Using` block:

```vb
Dim folderPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
Dim fileName = "SAMPLE.EXE"
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)

Using data = My.Resources.PICTURE
    SaveToFile(data, filePath)
End Using
```

Now it is up to you to carry out the same steps for an ICO file. If you are a hands on learner then get your hands on.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding, but I'll be honest. 
After attempting to rewrite the code. I got so many errors. Also I'm having trouble making sense of what you explained compared to what you've provided. I'm a very hands on learner, so I apologize if it may seem like a waste of your time.

Comment: Any property of `My.Resources` gives you an object but the type of that object depends on the type of the file you embedded. What you need to do is find out what type that object is for any particular resource and then work out how to save an object of that type. That is a different problem for `Byte` arrays, `Image` objects and `Icon` objects so you should not be asking about them all in the same question. How to save each of them is the same whether they come from a resource or not so the resource part is irrelevant to the actual problem. I showed you how to save an `Image` object.