# VB.NET 2010 - Extract/Save ICO file from My.Resources

Tags: vb.net, image, resources, icons

Title says it all, How do I save a file from the application resources to the desktop for example?

In the future it will create a directory and store it in there, essentially I'm making a game installer, but none of this matters right now.

I have tried about 6 different code methods and all of them failed, kept throwing errors about not being able to convert an icon/image to a `1-dimensional array`. Or that "Icon" or "Image" is not a member of `System.Drawing.Icon`

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you!

EDIT: Posting some code I've tried.

#1 ('Length' is not a member of System.Drawing.Icon)

`Dim File01 As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\" + "EXAMPLE_Icon.ico", IO.FileMode.Create) File01.Write(My.Resources.EXAMPLE_Icon, 0, My.Resources.EXAMPLE_Icon.length) File01.Close()`

#2 ('System.Drawing.Icon' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte)

`Dim filePath = Path.Combine("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\", "EXAMPLE_Icon.ico") File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, My.Resources.EXAMPLE_Icon)`

#3 ('RawFormat' is not a member of 'System.Drawing.Icon')

`Dim filePath = Path.Combine("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\", "EXAMPLE_Icon.ico") Using icon = My.Resources.EXAMPLE_Icon icon.Save("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\", icon.RawFormat) End Using`

Comment: You should post all 6 things youve tried and failed with. Even your failures are important clues to us to know how  your mind is approaching (even if it isnlt uscceeding) at the problem, which in turn tells us how to teach you better. If we can correct the underlying misunderstandings then the knowledge has a better chance of sticking/we can better imagine ways to teach you effectively

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. I am a very tactile/kinesthetic learner. So I need hands on with working code to then pull it apart and understand how it works to then modify/manipulate it. I will look back through all my code and post what I have, I may have been exaggerating on the "6", but I'll post what I have.

Comment: You just need `Dim ico = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("[Icon Name]"), Icon)`, then call `ico.Save()`, passing an open FileStream as argument. See whether this method is among those that don't work for you, then post the code you tried to make it work.

Comment: Thank you, Caius & Jimi! I will try Jimi's provided examples and come back to check on the post.

Comment: I have just tried the code examples that Jimi provided. I think I am misunderstanding how to implement the given code.

Comment: Well done on ignoring pretty much everything I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225331/vb-net-2010-extracting-an-application-resource-to-the-desktop). One thing I said specifically was that you should try to find out how to save an `Icon` to a file and you've obviously made no effort at all. I just did a web search for *"vb.net save icon to file"* and the second match was the documentation for the `Icon.Save` method but you have made no attempt to use that, suggesting that you don't even know it exists. If you don't even do a web search then you haven't tried.

Comment: Pardon my effort to avoid blowing up your notifications. I'm not active on here enough to notice what you post the second you post it, and when I do have time, I'm looking for a quick fix that I can study/modify later. I did know that `Icon.Save` exists, and I have tried it. However, the instances that I have tried it were clearly wrong based on the amount of errors. I clearly misunderstood how to implement `Icon.Save` and failed to mention it. Happy? Good.

Answer (score 2):

- Build the destination path using [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) when the path is composited.
- Many known System locations have a predefined value in [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder): in your case, **`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`**. [Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) accepts one of these values and returns the correct file system path.
  This returns the Path of the Desktop folder for the current User:

  ```
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
  ```
- The Icon object has a [Save()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.save) method that accepts a Stream as argument.
  You can pass a [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream) to save the Icon to a File, preserving its format, or a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream), then use [File.WriteAllBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes) to save the MemoryStream's buffer calling its **`ToArray()`** method.

Using a Resource name, as a string, using [ResourceManager.GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject):

```
Dim iconPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "myIcon.ico")

Using stream As New FileStream(iconPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None),
    ico = TryCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("myIcon"), Icon)
    ico?.Save(stream)
End Using
```

Or, depending on what fits better in the context of your operations:

```
Using stream As New FileStream(iconPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    My.Resources.myIcon.Save(stream)
End Using
GC.Collect()
```

Note: here, I'm calling [`GC.Collect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect) after calling `Save()` directly on the Icon object generated by [`My.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-resources-object). The Docs don't exactly explain it: `My.Resources` is a factory, it doesn't *return the object stored in the Project's Resources*, it generates a new object (a different one each time) from the data stored as a Resource. With `My.Resources.myIcon.Save(stream)`, we create a new object, save its data to disc, but never actually dispose of it. Calling `GC.Collect()` right after, the memory used is reclaimed immediately. If we don't, that memory is never reclaimed (we're *leaking*).

It's probably better to assign the generated object a to temporary variable declared with a `Using` statement. The two methods that follow can make use of `GC.Collect()`, calling it right after, to reclaim the allocated memory immediately, but it's not strictly required, we're not really leaking resources.
Open up Visual Studio's `Diagnostic Tools` to test the behavior with and without `GC.Collect()`, calling these methods multiple times.

```
Using stream As New FileStream(iconPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None),
    ico = My.Resources.myIcon
    ico.Save(stream)
End Using
' GC.Collect()  <= Not strictly required, but test the difference
```

Or using a MemoryStream:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(),
    ico As Icon = My.Resources.myIcon
    ico.Save(ms)
    ms.Position = 0
    File.WriteAllBytes(iconPath, ms.ToArray())
End Using
' GC.Collect()  <= Not strictly required, but test the difference
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd advocate calling GC.Collect after saving a single icon, as it could lead the reader to believe it needs to be done every time (or worse, after every Using). In practical terms it should be seldom called, if ever, and not without the developer being fully aware of why they're doing it. "Someone on the Internet wrote it so I just pasted it in and I don't know why" wouldn't be a good enough reason for me

Comment: @Caius Jard Not *after every `Using`*, the first method doesn't have it. But you're right, I'll add a couple of notes: it's interesting to test the difference with or without `GC.Collect()` in different conditions (I assume a Dev would put code under test to see what's what, but I may be wrong here :).

Comment: Hah, yeah I live in hope that SO users think deeply about the answers they receive, retain a sense of ownership of their problem, work through minor typos, carefully test and *don't* just blindly paste the first thing that seems to work.. But the universe is ever willing to [remind me how wrong I am](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow) 